# CSS3 transform + jQuery flip card issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/pwbu4/6/

I am using jQuery to control the `transform` property in CSS3 to create a "flip-card" effect. In the demo, if you hover the pink square, it will flip downward and show the back side. The problem is if you move the cursor on the pink square position, the animation will start again. It is supposed to flip the square only when `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. So basically when you move on the square, it is not even leaving the square because the flip is done by `rotateX`. So how can I fix that?

Comment: is this acceptable ? http://jsfiddle.net/pwbu4/7/ lol

Comment: @Esailija - I don't really like extra variables... It is not working like what I expected...

Comment: how about this http://jsfiddle.net/pwbu4/8/

Comment: you can't use mouseleave to revert the animation this way, because by the time the animation is over, you are no longer hovering over the div

Comment: @Esailija - I based on your demo and improved a little: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/pwbu4/10/ It works now! Thanks!

Comment: @Esailija I think that looks good, the only thing left to do is to set the width for `div.world` to something reasonable, otherwise you couldn't get the card to flip back if you stayed within the `div.world`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Esailija's comment and improved a little but, adding another wrapper will fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/pwbu4/11/